# Installing another Python version alongside Enthought Canopy

Tags: enthought, canopy

I have Enthought Canopy installed to `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\`, I am having an issue with my code running in the Canopy environment whereby I am getting Kernel crashes with no error information provided. I want to install another version of Python to run the code through to see if I get the same results. I need to still have access to all my modules that are installed through Canopy - does anyone know how to do this when using Canopy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to use Canopy packages in another Python version (or vice versa). Also, because this is Windows, while you *can* have multiple installations of Python 2.7 if you know what you are doing, there's some risk of the two separate Python installations walking on each other via entries in the Windows registry. So before doing that, I would suggest that you try running your code in a Canopy Command Prompt, which uses the Canopy Python and packages, but separate from the Canopy GUI. You might get output that sheds light on your crash. Otherwise, you'll need to simplify your code to hone in on the place where the code crashes.

Comment: Brilliant - thanks a lot for the in-depth explanation.